# how to prevent width loading lazy in kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have implemented [kendo combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index)  in my blog but when i enter the webpage first time or refresh the page the width is loading very lazy i mean i have inserted the width code externally i mean to decrease the width of the box 
This is the code i have inserted code but after that i got result but it is loading very lazy as you can see in my [blog](http://vmyblogupdates.blogspot.in/)

```
<style>
.k-combobox{
   width: 225px !important;
}
</style>
```

```html
<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



        <div id="example" role="application">
      <div id="tshirt-view" class="demo-section k-content">
           
            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">Search</h4>
            <select id="size" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 100%;" >
              <option />Vijay    <option />Kumar
              <option />Software
              <option />Gamer
              <option />Businessman
              <option />Thats all
            </select>
     
            
        </div>
        
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // create ComboBox from input HTML element
                    
                    // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                    $("#size").kendoComboBox();

                   
     var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");


    
                });
            </script>
        </div>

<style>
.k-combobox{
   width: 225px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code here:

```
   <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                       $("#size").hide(); 
                       // create ComboBox from input HTML element
                        $(window).load(function(){
                              $("#size").show();
                              $("#size").kendoComboBox();


                               var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");
                        });
                        // create ComboBox from select HTML element




                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: Remove the browser Cache, it is CSS or design issue. I checked perfectly. it's works.